# django specifc stack trace when running migrations in django.

Tags: python, django, postgresql

here are the database tables I have made

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', blank=True, related_name='venue', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)



class Address(models.Model):
    street1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 2, blank =True)
    zipcode = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
```

and here is the stacktrace it seems to be django specifc. Anyone see this before?

```
 Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, venue
Running migrations:
  Applying venue.0002_auto_20161220_2343...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 21, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 395, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 147, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 221, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 909, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 755, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 938, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/rickus/211hospitality/com.suitsandtables/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 946, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

I am using a postgress backend. The looks of my code and migrate, it all makes no sense. Rather frustrating.

Comment: Can you post the content of `venue.0002_auto_20161220_2343`?

Comment: The answer is in your migrations.

Comment: @EmettSpeer thank you. I realized that in the shower of all places. But now this begs the question, why does django go through previous migrations.

Comment: @amazingCarrotSoup each migration is only a differential of the previous migration. An example would be in migration 1 I have a table named `MyTable` and it has the field `name` in my next migration I have added the field `email`. When I run the migration Django needs to know what state the database should be in and then it apples the modification. It does the same thing when creating the migrations as well. This way you don't try to change a field that hasn't yet been created or update a deleted field.